# Overloaded lambdas in C++ and differences between clang and gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, overload-resolution

I'm playing with a trick to overload lambdas in C++.  Specifically:

```c++
// For std::function
#include <functional>

// For std::string
#include <string>

// For std::cout
#include <iostream>

template <class... F>
struct overload : F... {
    overload(F... f) : F(f)... {}
};      

template <class... F>
auto make_overload(F... f) {
    return overload<F...>(f...);
}

int main() {

    std::function <int(int,int)> f = [](int x,int y) {
        return x+y;
    };
    std::function <double(double,double)> g = [](double x,double y) {
        return x+y;
    };
    std::function <std::string(std::string,std::string)> h = [](std::string x,std::string y) {
        return x+y;
    };

    auto fgh = make_overload(f,g,h);
    std::cout << fgh(1,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fgh(1.5,2.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fgh("bob","larry") << std::endl;
}
```

Now, the above program compiles and works fine in clang:

```
$ clang++ -g -std=c++14 test01.cpp -o test01
$ ./test01
3
4
boblarry
```

It does not compile in gcc:

```
$ g++ -g -std=c++14 test01.cpp -o test01
test01.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test01.cpp:36:25: error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous
     std::cout << fgh(1,2) << std::endl;
                         ^
In file included from test01.cpp:5:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note: candidates are: _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = std::basic_string<char>; _ArgTypes = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]
     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note:                 _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = double; _ArgTypes = {double, double}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note:                 _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {int, int}]
test01.cpp:37:29: error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous
     std::cout << fgh(1.5,2.5) << std::endl;
                             ^
In file included from test01.cpp:5:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note: candidates are: _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = std::basic_string<char>; _ArgTypes = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]
     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note:                 _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = double; _ArgTypes = {double, double}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note:                 _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {int, int}]
test01.cpp:38:35: error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous
     std::cout << fgh("bob","larry") << std::endl;
                                   ^
In file included from test01.cpp:5:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note: candidates are: _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = std::basic_string<char>; _ArgTypes = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]
     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note:                 _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = double; _ArgTypes = {double, double}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/functional:2434:5: note:                 _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {int, int}]
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Why is there a difference?  For the record, I'm using gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.0.

---

## Edit 1

Evidently, this snippet of code failed to compile on VC as well and had already been [reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/990223/overloaded-lambda-pattern-fails-to-compile).  That being said, Sean Middleditch  posted a working version of the overloaded code:

```c++
template<class F1, class... Fs>
struct overload : F1, overload<Fs...>
{
    using F1::operator();
    using overload<Fs...>::operator();
    overload(F1 f1, Fs... fs) : F1(f1), overload<Fs...>(fs...) {}
};

template<class F1>
struct overload<F1> : F1
{
    using F1::operator();
    overload(F1 f1) : F1(f1) {}
};


template <class... F>
auto make_overload(F... f) {
    return overload<F...>(f...);
}
```

I'm still interested in understanding why this version of the overloaded lambda code works, but the original one does not.

Comment: This may just be due to the simplifying of your code for this question, but since you're using C++14, `[](auto x, auto y){return x+y;}` would produce a lambda with the same overloaded capabilities.

Comment: @DrewDormann For sure.  Really, I was just trying to come up with a single example to show what was going on.  Later, I'd like to use it for more complicated cases.

Comment: It's surprising that the original code compiled in clang. The general rule is that the same names in different base classes do not overload.

Comment: @T.C. operator lookup, maybe?

Comment: @dyp No, this case involves standard lookup of `operator()` in the context of `(fgh).operator()` ([over.call.object]/p1). The result of that lookup is clearly ambiguous.

Comment: Simplified example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7470dd2f07b1aa14

Comment: Stop using `std::function` when is completely unnecessary. It is a bad practice and less experienced people will learn it from code like this.

Comment: You aren't overloading lambdas, you are overloading `std::function`s.  Lambdas and `std::function`s are unrelated types.  As an aside, I'd want to binary tree inherit myself, instead of linear, just to keep things cleaner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like a Clang bug to me.

The general rule is that member functions of the same name in different base classes do not overload. For example:

```
struct Foo { void bar(); };
struct Baz { void bar(int); };
struct Quux : Foo, Baz { };

int main() { Quux().bar(); } // error on both GCC and Clang
```

For whatever reason, Clang fails to diagnose this ambiguity for `operator()`.

A `using-declaration` lifts the named base class members to the derived class scope, allowing them to overload. Hence:

```
struct Quux_2 : Foo, Baz { using Foo::bar; using Baz::bar; };
Quux_2().bar(); // OK.
```

In the working version of the code, the `using` declarations recursively bring every `operator()` declaration in the template arguments into the scope of the most derived class,  allowing them to overload.

Comment: This is because name lookup is done before overload resolution even starts, and name lookup finds both `Foo::bar` and `Baz::bar` of which neither is preferred?

Answer (score 10):

The original code **shouldn't** compile, gcc is correct here. See [class.member.lookup]:

> Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the resulting declaration set is empty), S(f,C) is
>   initially empty. If C has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f in each direct base class subobject Bi,
>   and merge each such lookup set S(f,Bi) in turn into S(f,C).
>   — [..]
>   — Otherwise, if the declaration sets of S(f,Bi) and S(f,C) differ, the merge is ambiguous...

The initial declaration set is empty (`overload` has no methods) - so merge all the bases, all of whom have differing sets. So the merge **should** fail. That rule only applies if the declaration set of `overload` is empty though, which is why the explicit adding of the `using F1::operator()` works.